# Pycharm not taking updated code in py files

Tags: python, python-3.x, eclipse, pycharm

Pycharm is not updating the code changes for next run. Lets say I have written a method with one parameter and I run that code. It works fine.

But If I change the method parameter to two or three and then I re-run the code again, It still says method is only having one parameter.

I think, Its not updating the code with Crtl+S as eclipse do. Please help.

Comment: are you running the code in the iPython console or in the "run" terminal?

Comment: If you are using the iPython console which I would only recommend for testing purposes you have to clear the variables for a new run if you changed code in different files